# Read a text file using with only a value using open and try to lock the file

Tags: c, linux, posix

I have a file text file like "~/MA14.txt" with only a value 0 or 1. I need to open the text file with the System call Open, (eventually lock the file until I am reading) and check if is the value is 0 or 1. I am testing the function with a file with 0.

The problem is the function returns 48 (ascii value of zero) and not the 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>


int get_permission(char *file_path_name);

int main() {
    char cwd[1024];
    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL)
        fprintf(stdout, "Current working dir: %s\n", cwd);
    else
        perror("getcwd() error");
    char str[80];
    strcpy(str, cwd);
    strcat(str, "/");
    strcat(str, "MA14");
    strcat(str, ".txt");
    printf("String obtained on concatenation: %s\n", str);
    int permission = get_permission(str);
    printf("permission is: %d\n", permission);
    return 0;
}


int get_permission(char *file_path_name){
    char c;
    size_t nbytes;
    nbytes = sizeof(c);
    int fd = open(file_path_name, O_RDONLY | O_EXCL);
    read(fd, &c, nbytes);
    printf("c = % d\n", c);
    close(fd);
    return c;
}
```

---

```
Current working dir: ~/cmake-build-debug
String obtained on concatenation: ~cmake-build-debug/MA14.txt
c =  48
permission is: 48

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Well yes, if it is an ascii character stored in that text file, so you will get the ascii code for the character in the file.  You can subtract `'0'` from the character to get its decimal value

Comment: @user3121023 Since they are returning an int, from the function, they need to actually get the integer value, so just printing it that way will probably only mask the problem.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianGibbons, I am honest to say that I didn't get your help with strtol

Comment: You probably want to return `c=='1'`

Comment: Yes, I removed the part of my comment with `strtol` as I realized it would not be appropriate with the code the way it is.  But if you subtract `'0'` from the character you read, assuming the character is a numeric character, you will get the decimal value of the character since the representations of the characters are in numeric order.

Comment: ASCII is a direct mapping of characters to numeric values. Thus, ASCII encoded characters are actually just byte-sized integers. When you read in a `char` digit, it can be converted to its numeric value by unmapping the digit: `'9' - '0' == 9` (which is literally the operation 57 - 48 == 9 under the hood).

Comment: As a fun challenge, maybe try this exercise again with the `mmap` syscall so that you can directly dereference the byte in your file from virtual memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you provided has three error and for this you can't get the wanted result.

The first error is in function declaration because the return type has to be char.

> char get_permission(char *file_path_name);

The second is when you print the value of c in get_permission because printf has to print a char [%c] not an integer [%d].

> printf("c = %c\n", c);

The third is in main function because you have to adjust types knowing what we said above.

> int permission = get_permission(str);
>
> printf("permission is: %c\n", permission);

I repost the corrected code.
I hope you find it useful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

char get_permission(char *file_path_name);

int main() {
    char cwd[1024];
    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL)
        fprintf(stdout, "Current working dir: %s\n", cwd);
    else
        perror("getcwd() error");
    char str[80];
    strcpy(str, cwd);
    strcat(str, "/");
    strcat(str, "MA14");
    strcat(str, ".txt");
    printf("String obtained on concatenation: %s\n", str);
    int permission = get_permission(str);
    printf("permission is: %c\n", permission);
    return 0;
}

char get_permission(char *file_path_name){
    char c;
    size_t nbytes;
    nbytes = sizeof(c);
    int fd = open(file_path_name, O_RDONLY | O_EXCL);
    read(fd, &c, nbytes);
    printf("c = %c\n", c);
    close(fd);
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options in the comments and I have a third one. The options are:

1. Subtract '0' to obtain the integer value.
2. Return c == '1'
3. Store the value as binary in the first place:

   ```
   char c = 0; // Note this is the integer, not '0'
   write(fd, &c, 1);
   ```

I would not advice the third option though. For what seems to be your use case, it is common practice to keep the file in text format (ASCII) so you can read it in a text editor for troubleshooting. So use either of the first 2 options.